# How do I put my list in to openAI's completion.create function?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a sample openAI's completion.create function in python to run a topic model model (= basically asking GPT to extract key topics).

The text data set is a **list** composed of +10,000 answers

How do I make GPT to read/loop into the contents inside the list?
I don't want to put all the answers as a raw text inside of the prompt parameter, but instead want to use list as a dataset.

any recommendation?

codes is as below

```
response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt="Read all of the contents within the topic_raw_data list and then extract key topics.",
  temperature=0.3,
  max_tokens=60,
  top_p=1.0,
  frequency_penalty=0.8,
  presence_penalty=0.0
)
```

and my list is named **topic_raw_data**